# Algorithm for retry process

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, service

Let say that we have a series of function that needs to execute in a loop.

1. Get Setttings return `networkPath` & `localPath`.
2. Copy File from `networkPath`(from process 1) to another `localPath`.
3. Read file from `localPath` return `list of info`.
4. Save `list of info` into DB.

In normal execution I have this code.

```
public void StartProcess() {
    var settings = GetSettings();
    CopyFiles(settings);
    var listOfData = ReadFile(settings);
    SaveListOfData(listOfData);
}
```

`StartProcess` method will be executed in a loop in which it waits for a file to read.

What would be a nice way to handle in which a program/code can retry specific process?
For example  there's an error on number 2 process, the program should execute process 2 and skip process 1.

Comment: `...the program should execute process 2 and skip process 1..` does that mean that you are ok with sending stale data?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements.  What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Hi @Roma, Lets say I store ProcessId, how about its parameters to call `CopyFiles(settings)`(Process2). In this case it should skip `GetSettings()` because on first loop it already processed then continue already in `CopyFiles(settings)`(Process2).

Comment: Hi @npinti, what do you mean by ok with sending stale data?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use boolean variable to control this situation.

```
bool successrun = true;
        string settings = ""; // variable type should be same with return type of GetSettings()
        public void StartProcess() 
        {
            if (successrun == true)
               settings = GetSettings();

            successrun = true;
            //set successran = false on any error on the following mwthods
            CopyFiles(settings);
            var listOfData = ReadFile(settings);
            SaveListOfData(listOfData);
        }
```

For more than 2 processes :

```
string settings = ""; // variable type should be same with return type of GetSettings()

public void StartProcess() 
{
    if (successrun == true)
       settings = GetSettings();

    successrun = true;
    //set successran = false on any error on the following mwthods
    CopyFiles(settings);
    var listOfData = ReadFile(settings);
    SaveListOfData(listOfData);
}

void AnyMethodCallsStartProcessInLoop()
{
    int numberOfProcesses = GetNumberOfProcesses();
    int i = 0;
    bool procSuccess = true; 
    while ( i <= numberOfProcesses)
    {
        StartProcess();
        if (procSuccess == true)
            i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about if the other process has error, lets say on process 3 or error in process 4?

Comment: Question says it has 2 processes, if there are more processes then boolean variable do not solve problem, in this situation we must use integer or boolean array to hold succes value of each process

Comment: Sorry for that, It was only for an example.